# Riemann-Roch space $L(D)$ and and the relationship with the set of poles

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am studying Riemann-Roch spaces L(D) through the book Algebraic curves by W. Fulton.
I have the following problems:

1. In the book he motivates to define this space saying that:

"Let $D = \sum_{P \in X}n_PP$ be a divisor on $X$ . Each $D$ picks out a finite number of points, and assigns integers to them. We want to determine when there is a rational function
with poles only at the chosen points, and with poles no “worse” than order $n_P$ at $P$;
if so, how many such functions are there?"

Then, the Riemann-Roch space is defined as
$$L(D) = \{f \in K|\ \text{ord}_P(f) \geq -n_P,\ \forall P \in X\}.$$
The problem is that I am not able to understand the relationship of this space defined in this way, with the poles and zeros of these functions.

2. Defining the set in this way, we see that a rational function is in $L(D)$ if $f=0$ or $div(f) \geq -D$. Searching, I saw that if $n_P = n>0$, then $f$ can have a pole in $P$ of order at most $n$; and if $n_P = -n<0$, so $f$ must have a zero in order $P$ of at least $n$.

I didn't understand these last two statements about the poles and zeros of f.

Please, I need help to understand these two items, what is the real meaning of these topics. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're having trouble with? For instance, do you know what a pole or a zero means in this context? Do you know what the order of a pole or the order of a zero is?

Comment: Yesterday, I saw an excellent vídeo on this same topic explained by Fields medalist Richard Borcherds: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uRfbnJ2a-Bs Highly recommend it.

Comment: I'm having difficulties with this. How the poles and zeros fit in this context is one of my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example will help. Suppose $D = 3P - Q$. This divisor is hinting a zero of order $3$ at $P$ and a simple pole (that is, of order $1$) at $Q$. It is also useful to think that "the order of a product of functions is the sum of their orders". So, when you see a sum of orders or divisors, you can think of a product (and a difference represents a quotient). So, the condition $div(f)+ D\geq 0$ means that $f$, multiplied by something with a triple zero at $P$ and a simple pole at $Q$, must be holomorphic everywhere.

The condition $ord_x(f)\geq -n_x$ for every $x$ means then that:

- $ord_P(f) \geq - 3$ means that $f$ has a pole at $P$ of order at most $3$ (or no poles at all). If $f$ has a simple or double pole at $P$ ($ord_P(f) =-1,-2$), then the condition holds. If $f$ is holomorphic at $P$ ($ord_P(f)\geq 0$), then it also holds. If $f$ has a pole of order $4$ ($ord_P(f)=-4$), it doesn't hold. The expression $(f) + D\geq 0$ here means that $f$, when multiplied with "something" which has a zero of order $3$ at $P$ (so that their orders are summed together), gives something with order $\geq 0$ at $P$ (that is, something holomorphic at $P$, with no poles). This is equivalent to $f$ having a pole of order $3$, at most.
- $ord_Q(f) \geq 1$ means that $f$ has a zero of order at least $1$. So, when its order is summed with $-1$ (i. e., when $f$ is multiplied by something with a simple pole at $Q$), the result has order $\geq 0$ (is holomorphic) at $Q$.

Since $n_x = 0$ for other points $x$ different than $P, Q$, the condition here means that $ord_x(f)\geq 0$ for those points. That is, $f$ is holomorphic at any other point (it can't have anymore poles!).

Comment: An excellent explanation. Helped me a lot! Thank you very much!